# Update jinternalframe table dynamically from another jinternalframe

Tags: java, mysql, database, swing, jtable

I have two jinternalframes with the first one is for viewing and the other is for the data processing. The data table of the first jinternalframe is the same as the second jinternalframe. What I want is to make the first jinternalframe updates its jtable after I added data from second jinternalframe. Please see attached photos of the first jinternal frame and the second jinternalframe.
[image: First Jinternalframe]

[image: Second jinternalframe]

And this is the code snippet for the first frame:

```
    table1 = new JTable();
    table1.setModel(loadTable1());
    scrollPane.setViewportView(table1);
    }
    public static DefaultTableModel loadTable1(){
    data = new ModelDB();
    tableModel1 = new DefaultTableModel();
    tableModel1.addColumn("ID");
    tableModel1.addColumn("Allocation");
    tableModel1.addColumn("Shipment Date");
    tableModel1.addColumn("Buyers");
    tableModel1.addColumn("Design");

    try{
        List<String> id = data.getAllocation().get(0);
        List<String> allocation = data.getAllocation().get(1);
        List<String> shipdate = data.getAllocation().get(2);
        List<String> buyers = data.getAllocation().get(3);
        List<String> design = data.getAllocation().get(4);

        for(int i=0;i<id.size();i++){
            tableModel1.addRow(new Object[]{
                    id.get(i),allocation.get(i),shipdate.get(i),buyers.get(i),design.get(i)
            });
        }
    }catch(Exception ex){}

    return tableModel1;
}
```

And this is the code snippet for the second frame:

```
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt){
    data = new ModelDB();
    String action = evt.getActionCommand();
    String allocation = txtAllocation.getText().toUpperCase();
    Date shipdate = (Date) shipDate.getModel().getValue();
    String buyers = String.valueOf(model4.getCheckeds()).replaceAll("[\\[\\](){}]", "");
    String design = String.valueOf(model.getCheckeds()).replaceAll("[\\[\\](){}]","");
    String stylecode = String.valueOf(model2.getCheckeds()).replaceAll("[\\[\\](){}]", "");
    String sizes = String.valueOf(model3.getCheckeds()).replaceAll("[\\[\\](){}]", "");
    String pcspack = txtPcsPack.getText();
    String season = txtSeason.getText().toUpperCase();
    String orderqty = txtQtyOrder.getText();

    if(action.equals("Add")){
        btnSave.setText("Save");
        btnSave.setActionCommand("Save");
        btnCancel.setEnabled(true);
        txtAllocation.setEnabled(true);
        txtAllocation.grabFocus();
        shipDate.setEnabled(true);
        cmbBuyers.setEnabled(true);
        cmbDesign.setEnabled(true);
        cmbStyleCode.setEnabled(true);
        cmbSize.setEnabled(true);
        txtPcsPack.setEnabled(true);
        txtSeason.setEnabled(true);
        txtQtyOrder.setEnabled(true);
    }
    else if(action.equals("Save")){
        if(allocation.isEmpty() || shipdate.equals("") || pcspack.isEmpty() || season.isEmpty() || season.isEmpty() || orderqty.isEmpty() || buyers.isEmpty()||
                design.isEmpty() || stylecode.isEmpty() || sizes.isEmpty()){
            message.showMessageDialog(null, "Nothing to save");
        }
        else{
            try{
                if(data.addAllocation(allocation, shipdate, buyers, design, stylecode, sizes, pcspack, season, orderqty) == true){
                    message.showMessageDialog(null, "Data have been successfully saved");
                }
                else{
                    message.showMessageDialog(null, "Failed to save");
                }
            }catch(Exception ex){
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
            table1.setModel(loadTable());
        }
        btnSave.setText("Add");
        btnSave.setActionCommand("Add");
        btnCancel.setEnabled(false);
        txtAllocation.setEnabled(false);
        shipDate.setEnabled(false);
        cmbBuyers.setEnabled(false);
        cmbDesign.setEnabled(false);
        cmbStyleCode.setEnabled(false);
        cmbSize.setEnabled(false);
        txtPcsPack.setEnabled(false);
        txtSeason.setEnabled(false);
        txtQtyOrder.setEnabled(false);

        txtAllocation.setText("");
        model.removeChecks();
        model2.removeChecks();
        model3.removeChecks();
        model4.removeChecks();
        txtPcsPack.setText("");
        txtSeason.setText("");
        txtQtyOrder.setText("");
    }

    else if(action.equals("Cancel")){
        btnSave.setText("Add");
        btnSave.setActionCommand("Add");
        btnCancel.setEnabled(false);
        txtAllocation.setEnabled(false);
        shipDate.setEnabled(false);
        cmbBuyers.setEnabled(false);
        cmbDesign.setEnabled(false);
        cmbStyleCode.setEnabled(false);
        cmbSize.setEnabled(false);
        txtPcsPack.setEnabled(false);
        txtSeason.setEnabled(false);
        txtQtyOrder.setEnabled(false);

        txtAllocation.setText("");
        model.removeChecks();
        model2.removeChecks();
        model3.removeChecks();
        model4.removeChecks();
        txtPcsPack.setText("");
        txtSeason.setText("");
        txtQtyOrder.setText("");
    }
}
```

Comment: You're posting some vague desires, code snippets and images, and I'm not sure how any of us will be able to understand your problem that would allow us to create a coherent answer. If you don't get one of these soon, please consider working to provide more focus to your code, your problem and your question, including creating and posting a valid [mcve] and asking a very specific and answerable question. Good luck.

Comment: ................hello?

Comment: Please note also that the two jinternalframes are in two different class...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The table of the first jinternalframe is the same as the second jinternalframe.

It can't be the same table because a Swing component can only have a single parent. So you must have two tables.

> What I want is to make the first jinternalframe updates its jtable after I added data from second jinternalframe.

So maybe you are saying you want the "data" to be the same in both tables.

If this is the case then you can share the `TableModel` between the two tables. Then when the data is changed in one it is automatically updated in the other:

```
DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(...);
JTable table1 = new JTable( model );
JTable table2 = new JTable( model );
```

If you want you can have different columns display in one of the table because you can remove a `TableColumn` from the `TableColumnModel`. Something like:

```
TableColumnModel tcm = table1.getColumnModel();
tcm.removeColumn( tcm.getColumn(...) ); // specify column number
```

or

```
table1.removeColumn( table1.getColumn(...) ); // specify column name
```

Comment: Yes, what I mean is that the data in the first jinternalframe table is the same as the data in the second jinternalframe table.

Comment: I tried your code and its still not updating the jtable of the first jinternalframe....

Answer (score 0):

Thanks [camickr](https://stackoverflow.com/users/131872/camickr) for the ideas I have solved my problem by letting the other frames access the table of the first frame. Also I fixed some of my codes to make it tidy by creating only instance of DefaultTableModel. This is the code that solves my problem:

Inside the first frame I add this:

```
public static JTable getTable(){
    return table1;
}
```

And inside the second frame I implemented it:

```
firstFrame.getTable().setModel(table.loadAlloc());
```